# joining error in a nested sql command - crystal reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I have this code below, but I keep getting an error that says A_NUM was specified multiple times for A.

```
SELECT Alleg,
       CASE 
             WHEN ALLEGCU LIKE '%F%' 
             OR ALLEGCU LIKE'%A%' THEN 'EF'
             ELSE ALLEGCU
         END,
         ALLEGCU
FROM

(SELECT *, CASE
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(ALL)), 1,1)) = 0
    THEN UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(ALL, CHARINDEX(' ', ALL)+1, LEN(ALL)
       - CHARINDEX(' ', ALL)))))
 ELSE ALL
                       END ALLEGCU

FROM ASSI_O 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN ALLS
      ON ASSI_O.A_NUM = ALLS.A_NUM ) A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A_NUM` column exists in both the tables `ASSI_O` AND `ALLS` and you are doing a `SELECT *` while doing the join.

Select only the needed columns and also prefix the table name to the column name

Changing `SELECT *` to `SELECT ASSI_O.A_NUM as ASSI_NUM, ALLS.A_NUM as ALLS_ANUM` should solve the problem

```
SELECT ASSI_O.A_NUM as ASSI_NUM, ALLS.A_NUM as ALLS_ANUM ...
```